# Is there any paid extension or all are free?

Tags: extension

All extensions are free or I have to pay a money for that. I am creating a extension then how will I get the money?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the CiviCRM extension directory all extensions are free. It is common in open source to share your work for free.

I am a freelance CiviCRM developer and all my extensions are free. However I get paid by clients for developing extensions for them and I then share those extensions for free.

So one way is to find clients and start working for them.

May I ask what brings you to asking this question? Is it that you like developing and you what some rewardds or is it something else?

Comment: I am working for one client. I am creating a extension for a client as per requirement. Is it necessary to publish that extension?

Comment: You don't have to publish it - but it will allow others to benefit from it & may help your client to maintain it going forwards

Comment: What about license?

Comment: in your info.xml in your extension the license will default to AGPL 3.0. But you can change that if you want to. : http://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.html